# Should a null character string be equal to a null-terminator in C?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, free, string-literals

Is there a difference between initializing a character array with null characters and with a null terminator ? These two examples:

```
char * result = ""
char * result = '\0';
```

The first one gives me an error but the other one is passable.

Function prototype:

```
char * form(int n, ...);
```

The code is:

```
char * result = "";
char *next;
char val_int[12];
int i;
va_list args;
va_start(args, n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int len = result ? strlen(result) : 0;
    sprintf(val_int, "%d", va_arg(args,int));
    next = val_int;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(len + strlen(next) + 1);

    strcpy(tmp, result ? result : "");
    strcat(tmp, next);

    free(result);
    result = tmp;
}
va_end(args);
return result;
```

Main function:

```
  char *s;
  s = form(3,123,456,789);
  printf("%s", s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
```

Comment: Does the first one give you an error because you don't have a `;`?

Comment: The character `'\0'` is equal to zero, which means that `char * result = '\0';` initializes `result` as a null pointer. This is very different from having a pointer point to the literal string `""`.

Comment: And in the future when asking about code giving build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Sorry there was a mistake when i cleaned up the code i edited it now, it didn't gave me an error because of it. The error is because i free up result but it isn't a valid pointer.

Comment: The posted code is initializing a pointer, not initializing an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first declaration

```
char * result = "";
```

declares a pointer to the string literal that contains one character: the terminating zero `'\0'`.

This declaration

```
char * result = '\0';
```

initialize the pointer by a null pointer constant and is equivalent to

```
char * result = NULL;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "";
    char *s2 = '\0';

    printf( "s1 == NULL is %s\n", s1 == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
    printf( "s2 == NULL is %s\n", s2 == NULL ? "true" : "false" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
s1 == NULL is false
s2 == NULL is true
```

As for the error you are saying about then its reason is this statement

```
free(result);
```

You may not free a memory occupied by a string literal. You may free a memory that was allocated dynamically.

When there is used a pointer initialized by the character literal `'\0'` then such a pointer is a null pointer and you may call `free` for a null pointer.

That is if you have a pointer initialized like

```
char * result = NULL;
```

that is the same as to write

```
char * result = '\0';
```

then you may call

```
free( result );
```

No action will be performed by such a call.

But if you will write

```
free( "" );
```

trying to free a string literal that has static storage duration you will get undefined behavior.

And this call

```
free( "" );
```

is equivalent to the following code snippet

```
char * result = "";
free( result );
```

Comment: So the first one isn't initialized ?

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic Why is not it initialized? It is initialized by the address of the string literal.

Comment: So the difference in those two is that the first one points to the terminating zero and the other one is initialized by it ? If the first points to the terminating zero could it be freed using the free() function ?

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic The difference is that the first one that was initialized by the string literal "" may not be used in a call of free because the memory occupied by teh string literal has the static storage duration. The second pointer initialized by the character literal '\0' is a null pointer. You may use a null pointer in a call of free. No action will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you attempt to free memory that wasn't allocated with `malloc`.

In C all literal strings are really stored (by the compiler) as arrays of non-modifiable characters.

When you have

```
char * result = "";
```

the compiler will create such an array for the empty string. It will contain one single element, the string null terminator. The initialization will make `result` point to the first element of that array.

And like any other array, you can't `free` it.

```
char * result = "";
free(result);
```

is basically the same as

```
char array[] = "";
char * result = array;
free(result);
```

It just makes no sense.

That is works with

```
char * result = '\0';
```

is because (as explained) that initializes `result` as a null pointer, and it's valid to pass a null pointer to `free` (it is a no-op).